# Recursive / hierarchy transform

Tags: typescript, generics

I have a function that takes an object with a children-array, of the same type.  Now I want to convert the list of children to a an object indexed by the children's ID.

I'd like to model this in Typescript, and do the following:

```js
export const convertHierarchyToDiffFriendly = <T extends {id: string, children?: T[]}, U extends T & {children: {[id: string]: U}}>(x: T): U => (<U>{
    ...x,
    children: x.children ? 
        <U["children"]>x.children.reduce((z, y) => ({
            ...z,
            [y.id]: convertHierarchyToDiffFriendly(y)}),
            <{[id: string]: U}>{}) : {}
})
```

This works, but:

```js
const convertedRhs = convertHierarchyToDiffFriendly(<IVendorStatusInput>rhs)
const c = convertedRhs.children["10"] // c's type is {}, not T & {children: {[id]: U}}
```

It's kind of obvious that U won't be derived correctly, but how could it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you want `U` to be generic.  Instead, you want it to be a function of the `T` type, using [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) types, something like this:

```
type ConvertToDiffFriendly<T extends { id: string, children?: T[] }> = {
  [K in keyof T]: "children" extends K ? { [id: string]: ConvertToDiffFriendly<T> } : T[K]
};
```

So `ConvertToDiffFriendly<T>` is the same as `T` except its `children` property (if it has one) is changed in type.  Now you can type your function like:

```
export const convertHierarchyToDiffFriendly = <T extends { id: string, children?: T[] }>(
  x: T
): ConvertToDiffFriendly<T> => ({
  ...x,
  children: x.children ?
    x.children.reduce((z, y) => ({
      ...z,
      [y.id]: convertHierarchyToDiffFriendly(y)
    }),
      <{ [id: string]: ConvertToDiffFriendly<T> }>{}) : {}
} as ConvertToDiffFriendly<T>)
```

I didn't check the implementation for correctness but the typings should be reasonable.

Finally, let's test it:

```
interface IVendorStatusThingy {
  id: string,
  children: IVendorStatusThingy[],
  limbs: number,
  withCheese: boolean
}
declare const rhs: IVendorStatusThingy;

const convertedRhs = convertHierarchyToDiffFriendly(rhs)    
const c = convertedRhs.children["10"] 
// c's type is ConvertToDiffFriendly<IVendorStatusThingy>
```

Looks good to me.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: You are right - this must be the way to go. Thank you!